# log-linear model and lmer function

Tags: r, panel-data

I am running a mixed effects model (random intercept, fixed slope) for panel data with the same entities reporting for several years of data. I have read about running a mixed effects model using lmer function in R, is it possible to use this linear regression model function to run a log-linear mixed effects model where the outcome is transformed by log()?

Comment: Yes, it is possible (and as straightforward as with `lm`).